# jquery datepicker not working in IE7 and IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

This is my js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("input#dateTill").datepicker();
});
```

My HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="dateTill" id="dateTill" class="input" value="20.1.2011" maxlength="10" size="10" style="margin-left: 0; background: url(images/icons/16_calendar.png) 75px center no-repeat;" />
```

The datepicker does work in all normal browsers like Firefox, Chrome, Opera. It does not work in IE7 and IE8.

When I click inside the input field, the datepicker window does not appear.

Any ideas? I am using jquery 1.4.4.

Comment: Checked your code in an IE8 and worked....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, just to be sure, don't use the same string for the id and the name property.
And for God's sake, don't define your class with a reserved word like *input*, it's and internal class/element already. Go for something like *pickerClass*.
Also, I think your jQuery selector syntax is wrong, no need for the *input* part, you already have an id for that element. This:

```
$("#dateTill").datepicker();
```

OR

```
$("input.pickerClass").datepicker();
```

if for some strange reason you want to select multiple inputs at once.
Also, if you have a CSS defined class already then move the inline styling into the CSS if it's gonna be used for more input fields.

Comment: @Dunhamzzz Of course, it has nothing to do with my problem. All of the issues listed by crowicked should have no effect on the datepicker functionality. They might be semantic or presentational mistakes/issues but they should not hve any effect on my problem.

Comment: Have you tried what I suggested or just saying it shouldn't in advance?
Yes, they probably SHOULDN'T have but we're talking IE here (yes, harsh again). Stick with good practices of coding and you'll avoid a lot of headache. I got to my conclusion by comparing your code with the sample code on jQuery UI dialog page (that works in IE8, already checked), I suggest you do the same.

Debug suggestion: delete all your customization of the dialog and add one at a time to see where it breaks.

Sorry if I sound cocky.

Comment: Yeah you have to remember that IE can break everything over the most trivial matters, putting an extra comma at the end of an object property list is the worst one. Cleaning/Optimizing your code may very well fix any IE issues. Make sure the HTML is as valid as can be as well.